# Exp:resso Store - add shipping cost after shipping country selected

Tags: expresso-store

Is it possible to add shipping cost on the summary checkout page? ie *after* the user has selected shipping destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a multi-part checkout it is as simple as putting the shipping options tag pair on any step after the user has entered their shipping details.

If you are allowing users to sign-up for memberships and have linked the billing & shipping details either to custom member fields or ZooVisitor fields the users should have this repopulated on subsequent visits so it shouldnt be an issue.

Something that I usually employ on the stores that I build if shipping/taxes come into play is to have a calculate tax and shipping field that is displayed in the cart summary area.

So once a user has added an item to their cart I would show the cart summary with an input for their shipping city & state. Once they fill the data you update the cart which should now get relevant shipping and tax information setup for them before they even get to the checkout pages.

It should be noted that you need to use the `{expo:store:checkout}` tag pair to show your cart summary with this approach since the `{exp:store:cart}` tag **does not** output form tags for performance reasons.